# Fedora 25 apache sendmail

Tags: php, apache, sendmail, fedora-25

I write script for forgotten password who send email with key with phpmailer. I have installed sendmail, but I can't configure correctly. I don't have a domain I want to use in localhost.

Somebody can tell me how to configure sendmail to work correctly?

Thank you

Comment: Save yourself the pain and use Mailgun.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a gmail account ? Or another one ?

Try this tutorial to configure the php sendmail option.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-gmail-or-yahoo-with-php-mail-function

Comment: I do everything in  this tutorial, but don't send email again.

Comment: locate may work after you issue `updatedb` command. But instead try `which msmtp` to see where it's hidding.

Comment: If I send email thus `echo "testmail" | msmtp myemail@domain.com` It's ok. But when I try with php doesnt work.

Comment: The chmod of the file is correct ? It won't work without a chmod of 600.

Comment: Yes chmod is 600.